# Unable to configure cloud storage for scheduled backup in Plesk Onyx

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, digital-ocean, onedrive, plesk

I've installed extensions such as Amazon S3 and Microsoft OneDrive and configured them to be "Ready for use". But I cannot find options to configure the scheduled backup using any of them.

**Screenshots:**

1. Remote storage configured:
   [WX20180420-024857@2x.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cEjH.png)
2. There's no remote storage options in scheduled backup: [WX20180420-024837@2x.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFiyQ.png)
3. But there is the remote storage options in "Back up now": [WX20180420-024939@2x.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwncP.png)

Is there an old thread here or can you guide me on how to solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [description of Amazon S3 Backup extension](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/8762049b-870e-47cb-ba14-9f055b99b508-s3-backup#!), it is an upcoming paid feature:

```
Planned features:

* Schedule subscription-level backups to be stored in the cloud 
and configure a rotation policy for old backups.
    This is a paid feature.
```

Expect it to be released soon. The same goes for [Microsoft OneDrive Backup](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/a8e5ad9c-a254-4bcf-8ae4-5440f13a88ad-one-drive-backup#!).